# jQuery Datatables change cell data based on click

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use a jquery datatable that contains 6 column this table have to be changed based ob user interactive in the following steps :

**1.** Click start button will highlight the first row background (i.e gray color). (done!)

**2.** Change first customer status from **(waiting)** to **(in service)**. (need help)

**3.** After finish of serving the customer the user will click on next something will happen

*a-)* delete the selected row which it will be always row(0).

*b-)* customer #2 will be selected (highlight) and its status change from **(waiting)** to **(in service)**.

My important request is once I clicked on Start how can I change the status from **(waiting)** to **(in service)**?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#culist').DataTable({
    "searching": false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    });
});

$("#straps").on('click', function(event) {
   var table = $('#culist').DataTable();
   table.rows().iterator('row', function(context, index) {

   $(this.row(0).node()).addClass('selectd_Tr');
   });
});

$("#nxtps").on('click', function(event) {
});
$("#psps").on('click', function(event) {
});
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrdivx/0f3pa4pe)

Comment: What are you stuck with?

Comment: You should edit relevant code into the question (but keep the fiddle of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in the click event listener of the start button:

```
table.cell(0,5).data("In Service");
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f3pa4pe/3/), and here's the [cell() function docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29)